# R data.table fread using named colClasses without header (e.g. no col.names?)

Tags: r, data.table, fread

## update (June 2016)

col.names was added on data.table 1.9.6 so issue is over and everyone super happy :) I think I can now convert all my read.csv calls to fread calls without worries of destruction

## original question

using data.table 1.9.4

I'm importing read.csv calls to fread due to HUGE performance improvements we've noticed. Most issues I can handle but I've reached a point where I'm clueless and wonder if anyone has an elegent solution.

My problem is that I have named colClasses but the input has no header (it's a grep function), here's a silly example to make sense:

```
males.students <- read.csv(pipe("grep Male students.csv"), 
                           col.names=c("id", "name", "gender"), 
                           colClasses=(id="numeric"))
```

now in fread I still want the named colClasses but I have no col names so just using

```
males.students <- fread("grep Male students.csv"), 
                        colClasses=(id="numeric"))
```

fails with

> Column name 'id' in colClasses[[1]] not found

How can I fix that? are there plans to add col.names?

Comment: Since you know that it's the first column, you can just use column number for this. `colClasses=list(numeric=1))`.

Comment: Try using the `select` argument as well

Comment: @shadow this was obviously an extremely simplified example - the real csv has 40 column and I'm setting colClasses for 19 of them, and I really don't think it's reasonable to use column numbers, u want your system to be robust and allow changes without having your data mysteriously change types without ever figuring out why.

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to set 19 col classes? What classes are they? If the data is clean they should read in correctly.

Comment: @RichardScriven select only lets you choose the columns u want returned by name/index, not change their names. I need to set colClasses because some columns might look like numbers but are actual only meaningful as characters, e.g. in financials an exchange order ids "00000000123" and "00000123" are different orders and that's only represented as characters but not as numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the names in the command line:

```
fread('echo "id,name,gender"; grep Male students.csv', colClasses = c(id='numeric'))
```

Comment: This hack won't scale for large files.

Comment: @smci huh, what's there to scale? there is no overhead from adding an `echo` on top of the existing `grep`

Comment: The `echo+grep` are using the command-line to create a temporary file which could be very large, and blow out memory. What if students.csv has 10M rows?

Comment: @smci OP is already working with `grep` to filter out the original file before reading it, as such, `echo` adds no overhead, and no memory penalty. If you can't read the grepped file, you certainly can't read the original.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the original question, if the problem is that `grep` removes the header, you could use `awk` instead, to print the first line and any lines containing "Male":

```
fread("awk 'NR==1 || /Male/' students.csv"), colClasses=(id="numeric"))
```

This might help people that still use the old version of `data.table`.