# Read csv files from HDFS into R using fread() and grep -- lost column names

Tags: r, data.table, hdfs

I've been trying to read large csv files from HDFS into R using the data.table package since it's a lot faster than the rhdfs package in my experience.

I have been successful with reading entire files with the following commands:

```
data <- fread("/usr/bin/hadoop fs -text /path/to/the/file.csv"), fill=TRUE)
```

Then, I would like to only read in rows that contain the value "2MS-US". I tried to do it with `grep`:

```
data <- fread("/usr/bin/hadoop fs -text /path/to/the/file.csv | grep '2MS-US'"), fill=TRUE)
```

This returns the correct number of rows, but it removes all the headers. They now become "V1", "V2", etc.

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602337/r-data-table-fread-using-named-colclasses-without-header-e-g-no-col-names), the issue with losing column names when using `grep` has been resolved in data.package 1.9.6, but I am still experiencing it even though I am using 1.9.7. Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Fixed the issue by using `sed` instead:

```
fread("hadoop fs -text /path/to/the/file.csv |sed -n '1p;/2MS-US/p'", fill=TRUE)
```

The `1p` part prints the first line, which are the headers, so this way I was able to keep the headers as well as the rows that match the string.